# Getting only one answer from a list python

Tags: python-2.7

I may have a noob question, but here it goes. I need to parse through a list and I need the return to be specific. Here is the code:

```
a = 11
bla = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

lista = []
for element in bla:
    if element == a:
        lista.append(element)
    else:
        lista.append('not found')
print lista
```

This way - the return is 10 times - 'not found' - and I need it only one time.
lista = ['not found']
Any ideas?

Comment: do you need to return as many times the element in the list, or just the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python's built in `lst.count()`

```
a = 11
bla = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

# get number of times a occurs in bla
cnt = bla.count(a)

# if cnt isn't zero then lista becomes a repeated cnt times, otherwise just not found
lista = [a] * cnt if cnt >= 1 else ["not found"]

print(lista)
>>>["not found"]
```

Edit:

Jean-François Fabre suggested are more pythonic version for building `lista`:

```
lista = [a] * cnt or ["not found"]
```

Edit 2:

If you want to do something similar for dictionaries you only have to implement the count function for yourself. I turned user into a string literal since making it a list and doing `user[0]` each time is pointless:

```
user = 'john'
user_details = [{u'UserName': u'fred', u'LastSeen': u'a'}, {u'UserName': u'freddy', u'LastSeen': u'b'}]

# get the count
cnt = sum(i['UserName'] == user for i in user_details)

#do what we did before
lista = [user] * cnt or ["not found"]
```

Edit 3:

Finally if you want to use a for loop, check if it's not found at the end instead of at each step:

```
user = ['john']

user_details = [{u'UserName': u'fred', u'LastSeen': u'a'},{u'UserName': u'freddy', u'LastSeen': u'b'}]
lis = []
for element in user_details:
    if element['UserName'] == user[0]:
        lis.append(element)
if not lis: lis.append("not found")
```

Comment: or `[a] * cnt or ["not found"]`

Comment: Thank you @Primusa - let me see if it works with strings as well from a dict - as this was just for example and it works  - thank you.

Comment: @lostprophet it will work for strings but dicts don't have a `.count()` method. However for a dictionary this is pointless since keys can't be repeated... unless you're trying to count the values in which case whatever carries over from lists or strings won't work anyway...

Comment: @Primusa - yup - I just found out - I cannot count in a dictionary. Uff - back to square 1.

Comment: @lostprophet why would you ask a question about lists if you want to count in a dictionary?

Comment: @Primusa - you are right - I was trying to break down and simulate using a list - but I mixed it up - I appologize for that.

Comment: @lostprophet see edit. If this answer solves your question please mark the answer is accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks :)